# Swift MVVM how can I implementing Array to model

Tags: json, swift, mvvm

Array inside the Rss Feed model and how can I solve this problem? I can't get data with MVVM from JSON.

Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Product]' to expected argument type 'Product'

I'm so sorry for bad English.

> RSSFeed Model:

```
struct RSSFeed: Codable {
        var title: String?
        var description: String?
        var icon: String?
        var items: [Product]?
    }
```

> Product Model:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var title: String?
    var specs: String?
    var size: [String]?
    var color: String?
    var link: String?
    var image: [String]?
    var price: Price
}
```

> Product View Model:

```
struct ProductViewModel {

    private var product: Product!

    init(product: Product) {
        self.product = product
    }

    var id: String {
        return product.id ?? ""
    }

    var title: String {
        return product.title ?? ""
    }

    var specs: String {
        return product.specs ?? ""
    }

    var size: [String] {
        return product.size ?? [""]
    }

    var link: String {
        return product.link ?? ""
    }

    var imageURL: [String] {
        return product?.image ?? [""]
    }

    var price: String {
        let rawValue = product.price.rawValue
        let currency = product.price.currency

        return "\(currency)\(rawValue)"
    }
}
```

> Product Provider (Problem is here)

```
class ProductProvider {

    static let product = ProductProvider()

    private init() {

    }

    func getProduct() -> [ProductViewModel] {
        var rssFeed = RSSFeed()

        let jsonFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "products", ofType: "json")

        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: jsonFile!))
        do {
            rssFeed = try JSONDecoder().decode(RSSFeed.self, from: data!)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if let product = (rssFeed.items) {
            return ProductViewModel(product: product)
//Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Product]' to expected argument type 'Product'
        }
        return [ProductViewModel]()
    }
}
```

How can I get JSON data ?

Comment: did you define `Price` as Codable too? every element of `Product` must be Codable

Comment: Yes sir. Price is Codable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if` clause to

```
if let items = rssFeed.items {
    return items.map {ProductViewModel(product: $0)}
}
```

Since one view model contains one product you need to convert the `items` array of `Product` to an array of `ProductViewModel` using the `map` function